# How to watch mounted DVD image in VLC?

Tags: dvd, vlc

Why VLC (in my case ver. 1.1.4) cannot open/play mounted Video DVD images /in Ubuntu 10.10 as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mounting the iso using another tool like gmountiso and then try playing with vlc. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works perfectly mounting video ISO image by mean of Gmountiso, than playing it in VLC.

Answer (score 16):

VLC can open iso files without them mounted.But why do you want to play a mounted image, instead of an iso directly ? If you cannot open them from open dialog just issue: vlc /path/to/file.iso in a console.

Comment: Thank you, answer is accepted! I will open ISO images directly from VLC.

Answer (score 2):

Open Media -> Open Folder -> select mounted dvd image folder

Answer (score 0):

Once the image is mounted, open VLC.

Click `File -> Open Directory`.

Navigate to the mountpoint of the DVD and open the VIDEO_TS folder.

Comment: I agree with the answer below (by karthick87) I think it is better to open ISO images directly in VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem playing from mounted HDD and I run this command and it fixed everything:

```
sudo apt install browser-plugin-vlc
```